# Expression for a table full of food

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Are there some commonly used expressions/phrases for when the table is full of dishes, bowls, etc.c (generally food)? In the sense the host has prepared a lot of food for the party, guests, etc. and it looks impressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The table **was groaning** under the weight of food prepared*.

Comment: Thanks, that's the expression!

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a great bounty. What a smorgasbord! A true cornucopia of goodies. A generous feast!

All of the above take a somewhat high voice, but that might be appropriate when complimenting such a show of hospitality. To call it an *impressive spread* might be more casual.

Comment: Yeah, *smorgasbord* is what I think of first.  It's used both literally and figuratively.